# How to select data from DIV's with something like $this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

given the following code snippet:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
  <div class="row" >
    <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
      <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
         <div class="card-header text-center">  {{ result.title }} </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text"  v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I read data from a random div/unknown position in for div? I can't use PHP.

This `<div ... id="networdapp">` is created depending on the results from a database. How can I get the data `{{result.title}}` from a random div when I click the "Details" button from it?

I tried to get it using JQuery but I ended up by selecting all data from all DIVs. Then I was thinking if I can do that with `$this` and I tried but still can't do it.

EDIT: There is the generated html code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Website Test</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <link rel="stylesheet"             href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>

        <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSite for testing</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarWw1" aria-controls="navbarWw1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarWw1">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="map">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="myInput" type="search" onkeyup="myFunction()"  placeholder="Find your next memories!">
      </form>
    </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp" style="display:none;">
       <div class="row" >
          <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
            <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light" >
               <div class="card-header text-center" > {{ result.title }}             </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text" v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="/details" class="btn btn-info" >Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script>

  function myFunction() {
      var input , filter , OK = false ;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  if(filter.length > 0 ) {
  document.getElementById("networdapp").style.display = "";
  $( ".col-sm-6" ).each(function( index ) {
  if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1){
  this.style.display="";
  }else{
  this.style.display="none";
  //document.getElementById("networdapp").style.display = "none";
  }
  });
  }
  else{
  document.getElementById("networdapp").style.display = "none";
  }
  }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    const vm = new Vue({
      el: '#networdapp',
      data: {
        results:[]
       },
       mounted() {
         axios.get('/getJson')
       .then(response => {
          this.results = response.data;
       })
       .catch( e => {
         console.log(e);
       });
      }
    });

    </script>

  </html>
```

Comment: You should show multiple rows in your example, most of the answerers didn't understand what you're doing.

Comment: So the real question is _How do i turn result.title into the actual data in vue.js?_

Comment: This is all the <body></body> content....As i said this <div id="networdapp" are generated,let's say n <div class="col-sm-6"> divs and I want to get the data from the {{result.title}} by clicking on a random "Details" button from these divs.For example if i have 10 col-sm-6 divs and i click the thrid "Details" button I want to get the data from the third {{result.title}}.

Answer (score 0):

The div has the class `card-header`, so...

```
$('.card-header').text()
//or
document.getElementsByClassName('card-header')[0].innerText
//or
document.querySelector('.card-header').innerText
//or
document.querySelectorAll('.card-header')[0].innerText
```

However, you want to get the one related to the button clicked.  So that could look something like...

```js
//create a delegate event handler on the container for all the buttons
$('#networdapp').on('click', '.btn.btn-info', function (e) {
  //prevent the link so the runnable snippet stops jumping back to the top
  e.preventDefault();

  //find the parent div with the card class that is the parent to both
  //the link and the title
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  //find the nested card header in the card clicked
  var $cardHeader = $card.find('.card-header');
  
  //console log the text
  console.log($cardHeader.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="networdapp">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
      <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
         <div class="card-header text-center">  title 1 </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text"  v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
      <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
         <div class="card-header text-center">  title 2 </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text"  v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="result in results" class="col-sm-6" >
      <div class="card m-3 h-240  bg-light">
         <div class="card-header text-center">  title 3 </div>
           <div class="card-body" style="height:200px" >
             <p class="card-text"  v-html="result.prevDesc"></p>
           </div>
             <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-info">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only get from the first row, not the row with the clicked button.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#networdapp .card-header.text-center").html()
```

So:

```
$(".btn.btn-info").click(function(){
    console.log( $("#networdapp .card-header.text-center").html() );
})
```

Or:

```
$(".btn.btn-info").click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).closest("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").html() );
})
```

Comment: The first two examples are wrong, they get get the HTML from the first row, not the clicked row.

Comment: @Barmar Try running them all in a fiddle. They work fine. E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mw3qhv7r/

Comment: Your fiddle only has 1 row! Try adding a second row to the fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar Where, in the question, does it say there's more than one row?

Comment: **How can I get the data {{result.title}} from a random div when I click the "Details" button from it?**

Comment: That implies that this is being repeated, and he wants to select the data from the same div containing the button.

Comment: @Barmar I prefer not to infer. And if that's the case, then the OP should post a representative code example. And then the answer would be to change `$(this).closest("#networdapp")` to `$(this).closest(".row")`

Comment: He also said that the contents are being generated from a database query. This is so obviously a table of database rows, you're being deliberately obtuse in not recognizing it.

Comment: @Barmar What does obtuse mean?

Comment: From the dictionary: "annoyingly insensitive or slow to understand".

Comment: @Barmar can't believe you actually answered that one

Comment: The first option gives me the result from the first div.The second and third gives me undefined.What a tricky problem...

This is what I've been testing till now:

function getData() {
window.alert($(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").text());
window.alert(console.log( $(this).closest(".row").find(".card-header.text-center").html() ));
}



P.S:I created an event on click for "Details" button just like that onclick="getData();"

Answer (score -1):

You can select div then use the context to select the button r other elements within.

```
$(".card").each(function(){
   var that = this; // <--- the current div
   var header = $(that).find(".card-header");
   var detailBtn = $(that).find(".btn-info");

   // set event handlers here
   // Example:
   detailBtn.click(function(){
     alert(header.text());
   });
});
```

Here is a working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6c8dxb59/2/)

Comment: Hi,when i try :
$(".card").each(function(){
   var that = this; // <--- the current div
   var header = $(that).find(".card-header");
   var detailBtn = $(that).find(".btn-info");

        window.alert(header.text());
   // set event handlers here
});
It gives me {{result.title}}

Comment: Yes, it does. What is the result that you were expecting?

Comment: The data from {{result.title}}

Comment: Are using a framework that is supposed to turn this into data? It looks like you have a templating engine that is supposed to turn this into data. But that's not what it said on the question.

Comment: @Ibu Looks like Angular. But where the data comes from seems to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: The data comes from a database,and yes I'm using a framework,Vue.js

Comment: @Barmar since he said "It gives me {{result.title}}" I understood that this vue is not properly running the for loop and replacing the variables.

Comment: @G.Emilian show us the generated  html code. Please add it to your question. You can get the generated code from the Elements tab on chrome

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery

```
$(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").text();
```

To remove unneccesay spaces you can use trim

```
$.trim($(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").text());
```

Comment: When i use the first command : 
window.alert($(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header").outerHTML);
or
window.alert($(this).parents("#networdapp").find(".card-header.text-center").outerHTML); it displays undefined....